# Redirect to Index / Navigation from Layout not loading page

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, redirect, asp.net-mvc-5

In none of my Action Methods in a controller, `RedirectToAction("Index")` is working. But in other controllers the `RedirectToAction(Index)` is working. When I give the URL : `Localhost:ControllerName` it is not redirected and gives me an error page stating the

> The resource cannot be found.

I am unable to navigate to the index page with the controller name alone. I also tried `RedirectToAction("Index","ControllerName")` which is not working either.

I have the similar thing in my other controllers working. The name of my COntroller is `ViewsController`. will this have any impact on the working of my `Redirect` ?

Index

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    return View(db.Views.ToList());
}
```

Create wher `RedirectToAction` is called

```
 public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "ViewsID,ViewsName,DescriptionEN,DescriptionDE")] Views views)
 {
     if (ModelState.IsValid)
     {
            db.Views.Add(views);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index","Views");
     }

     return View(views);
 }
```

Even in my layout

`@Html.ActionLink("Views", "Index", "Views")`

is not working.

What is causing the redirect to not function. I suppose there are no issues with my RouteConfig because similar redirects in other controllers are working

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a cascading issue and is (in my opinion) not worth the hassle. `Views` is a folder in your project containing all your .cshtml files. By using `ViewsController` you now assign a mvc route to it which means it's in conflict with an already assigned route.

Problem is there's a specific handler that prevents you from navigating here in `Views/web.config`.

```
<system.webServer>
  <handlers>
    <remove name="BlockViewHandler"/>
    <add name="BlockViewHandler" path="*" verb="*" preCondition="integratedMode" type="System.Web.HttpNotFoundHandler" />
  </handlers>
</system.webServer>
```

All we got to do is remove that right? Wrong. Physical files are mapped before MVC routes. So you'll (by default) get a nice 403 Forbidden because you're trying to directory browse.

To get around that you can use the `RouteExistingFiles` option in your Route.config.

```
routes.RouteExistingFiles = true;
routes.MapRoute(...);
```

This has the side-effect of ignoring any physical files you may want routed, though. But hey, at least it works now.

**Conclusion:** just rename your controller. It's way less painful.

Comment: Yes. I have already changed the name of my controller. It solved the issue.